# How to use buttons with onclick in template engine EJS?

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have this in my EJS Template:

```
<button type="button" id="getStatusButton" onclick="click()">Show something</button>
```

and this in my index.js:

```
function click(){
    console.log('Button clicked')
}
```

and

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('test', {});
});
```

The Button is shown on the view, but if I click the button, there comes the message that the function is not defined. I assume, I have to pass the function to the View but my approaches did not work. I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: check index.js file is properly loaded or not

Comment: Yes, I think so

Answer (score 1):

I changed to Handlebars now and there it'S working like a charme. So no need help anymore for me. :)